# Why don't my 2 functions give the same results?

Tags: python, neural-network

Below I have the code of my attempt to make a neural network with 2 inputs and 3 outputs. While the training gives good results, when I try to input the numbers, the results are way off. After I made some small changes, I observed that, even though they return the output from the function which should be the same, again, the results were different. The only explanation I can think of is that there is a bug.
The functions that I'm talking about are "train" and "result".

Here is the code:

```
from numpy import dot, exp, max, sum, random, array

class Network:
def __init__(self):
    self.w = random.random((2,3))


def sigmoid(self, x, derivate = False):
    if(derivate == True):
        return x * (1 - x)
    return 1 /(1 + exp(-x))

def train(self):

    trainingInput = array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
    trainingOutput = array([[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0]])
    n = 0

    while(n < 10000):
        exOutput = self.sigmoid(dot(trainingInput, self.w) - 0.1)
        error = trainingOutput - exOutput
        self.w += dot(trainingInput.T, error * 
    self.sigmoid(exOutput,True))
        n += 1


    return exOutput

def result(self):
    trainingInput = array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
    exOutput = self.sigmoid(dot(trainingInput, self.w) - 0.1)
    return exOutput
network = Network()
c = 0
d = 1
o = network.result()
output = network.train()

print(o)

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should first train and then check the results.
If you check it before training, obviously two results will be different.
you can just once again calculate the results after training, hopefully, this will solve your bug.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the function returns the output AFTER the training(after the while loop I made). Immediatly after the output in the first said function is made, the second one which should give me the same array starts.

Comment: I dont think so, see when you initialize your class object, that is network, you randomly initialize self.w . now you cal network.result(), this will print the result based on your randomly initialized sefl.w . afterward you call network.train(), this function updates your self.w.

Comment: If you are still confused, just go ahead and calculate o after your output. If it doesnt works , we will work it out.

Comment: I think I found the problem. Apparently, all the methods in a class will run at once, so the "result" method didn't update. However, I don't really know how to code so that this method will run after "train".

Comment: I dont think thats the problem, when you initialize the class, only your init method runs. to run other methods, you need to call them.In case you want to train your network to get results, do this. add a line inside results() : 'trainout=self.train()'

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to find a way to fix it for about an hour. Now it's fixed!